# Don't check suggested edit improvements as being more or less "substantiative"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

If a suggested edit is overall good but introduces some questionable formatting, I improve it to remove the bad changes. If it's approved before then, the edit is less substantiative, because it changes less things.

This is annoying; can it be changed to always consider edits more substantial than the edits they're improving? (Not when there's been an edit in between, just when it's been approved first.)

---

This is *doubly* annoying when the edit is stopped because the *title* was already edited. I know I'm improving the title, because I clicked the "Edit" button in the suggested edit review panel.

Comment: well, how else do you propose we handle editing conflicts?

Comment: @SamIam In this situation, there is no editing conflict. Two edits were submitted: the suggestion and the improvement. The improvement starts from the result of the suggestion.