# Bounty will become possible a year ago

Tags: support, bounties

On [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134324/allow-manual-override-for-edits), where the “start bounty” link should be, I see:

[image: question eligible for bounty Jun 5 ’12 at 0:00]

Haha, what? (Clicking it takes me to [the help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).)

Comment: I see the link and clicking it gives me the popup. What browser, OS and year are you posting from?

Comment: @Oded: Chromium 28.0.1500.95, Linux, 2013.

Comment: You are 15 years old. It's a bit early to desperately hold on to your youth...

Comment: I used you as an example last night, hope it is not a problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192211/217863

Comment: @Oded: Reproducible in Firefox 22.0 in the same year, freshly logged-in.

Comment: @apaul34208: Not a problem :)

Comment: Is that happening to you only on that question, or on others as well?

Comment: @Oded: Only on that question, as far as I can tell. (And it also happens with JavaScript disabled — if that helps any.)

Comment: Any javascript / network errors?

Comment: @Oded: None. (When I turn my extensions off.)

Comment: It would be fun if this were related to the fact that it was asked at 0:00:12 UTC. I’ll try to find another question like that.

Comment: @minitech - It _would_ be strange.

Comment: @minitech DIY metabugfix: you are the web developer, you fix it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have had bounties on this question before. Actually, you had a 500 bounty on it.

As result, you can't offer another bounty on it. Additionally, having < 500 rep doesn't help with the logic (say you had a 400 bounty there but < 450 rep - you can't offer a bounty).

This is why you are not seeing a `start a bounty` link - a fairly unique set of conditions - it is your own question, you have had a max bounty on it and you have less rep than what the max for a bounty is.

This is a real edge case - not sure what we will do about it.

Comment: So where is the code getting the date from? And since you already have logic that selectively displays the "start a bounty" link, why can't you also hide the eligibility message?

Comment: So does this only happen on my own questions? I found [another one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165866/dont-check-suggested-edit-improvements-as-being-more-or-less-substantiative) “question eligible for bounty Feb 3 at 16:29”, but [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94311/why-doesnt-the-stack-exchange-store-support-paypal) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/it-should-be-possible-to-submit-improvements-to-a-suggested-edit-even-when-the-s) have hidden the links, as it should be.

Comment: @Oded - I'm fairly certain I've had a 500 bounty on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127130/careers-change-order-of-sections-in-pdf-export) but I still see the start bounty link.  Am I misreading your post?

Comment: @AdamRackis: At 500, you can start another 500. And you have 13,918 rep.

Comment: Ahh - thanks - got it.  I don't think I've ever seen a moderator with < 500 rep on meta :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: I had 1 once. There’s a 2014-04-01 bug report preview for you there, by the way ;)

Comment: @minitech - ha!  Creating posts on 4/1 is a fine art.  I'm fairly proud of my net score of zero on [my last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965146/creating-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @AdamRackis - There is a specific set of conditions here. Including having rep < 500.

Comment: Well <click, click> a certain mod is no longer < 500, so problem solved :-D

Comment: @minitech - Yes, own question is also one of the conditions... Like I said - a real edge case. I will look at it tomorrow to see if we can make this a bit saner (we shouldn't display a message like this anyways - not for a bounty start in the past)

Comment: @minitech - Now that you have > 500 again, you should be able to see the link...

Comment: Aaaaaaand it's gone.

Comment: *"not sure what we will do about it."* I suggest we can keep *add bounty* link with a message somewhat like we did for [*add comment*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191343/187824)

Comment: @hims056 - currently, just changed it to make more sense if it happened in the past.

Comment: @Oded - You mean you have already implemented it?

Comment: @hims056 - not 5 minutes ago. Still needs to be deployed.

Comment: I still think it's a bug... worst case just hide the link altogether in my opinion but don't show malformed information.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it isn't wrong information. The _question_ is eligible for a bounty. It is just the case that the user is not able to offer one (so, _others_ can offer a bounty, which is a different case from a question that is not eligible for a bounty at all - say a new question)

Comment: @Oded well, when I have 3 active bounties (and it happens a lot here on Meta :)) I simply don't see any "start bounty" link. Why this should be different?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This is for _own_ questions only. It informs the user that _their_ question is eligible (and they could post a bounty if they had enough reputation)

Comment: @Oded I see. Still think it better be hidden in those corner cases but agree it's not that important. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It is such an edge case, that I don't see the need to change it.

Comment: @Oded well, I now have 3 active bounties and posted a new question. I don't see the "question eligible for bounty" at all.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Correct. No one can post a bounty within 2 days of the question being posted. The _question_ is not eligible for a bounty yet ;) - once it is eligible, you will see the link. Check your _old_ questions.

Comment: @Oded what I mean is that I did see it before starting the third bounty then it disappeared into thin air.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That's expected. You have more reputation than the max bounty reputation. Again - what happened here is extremely rare and anyone with lots of rep will not encounter it. Drop below 500 and we'll talk ;)

Comment: @Oded will take some time... let's see. Can get rid of 1500 every 24 hours... 27798 / 1500... 18.5 days. Shall I start? ;D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Assuming no reputation gains within that timeframe... though I will not be around to confirm at that date.